# How to delete angular storage when closing the browser?

Tags: angularjs

Angular store values are still available when we close the browser and reopening the browser.  I need to get empty angular store value when reopening the browser.

Comment: Angular store value or  local Storage value stored by angular ?

Comment: or you mean cookie storage?

Comment: Iam using Angular storage and injected "store" dependency. here is my code  store.set('key');

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us? Kinda hard to figure out how you're storing the data

Comment: module.service('UserService',
    function UserService ($http, store) { store.set('testkey', "testing store");});

Comment: @areddy, I think `Angular storage` is an external module. Can you add link to that module?